# How does gzipped tar creation works?

Tags: gzip, tar

I presume that this command first creates tar file and then gzip's it.
    tar -zcvf file.tgz /somefolder

The question is, is full .tar file first written somewhere on the disk and then gzip'ed, or is it put in RAM memory and gzipped from there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both gzip and tar are running at the same time, with tar piping its output into gzip.  The entire tar file never exists anywhere, either in RAM or on the disk.  Chunks of the tar file exist temporarily in RAM before being compressed by gzip, and the compressed output is written to disk.